System of matrix equations
Consider the following system of matrix equations to be solved in the variables $A$ and $B$:
$$\begin{cases} 
&A^{\top}PA=K \\
&B^{\top}PB=M \\
& A^{\top}PB = N
\end{cases} $$
where: $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times u}$ are my unknowns and $P \in \mathbb{S}_+^{n\times n},  K \in \mathbb{S}_+^{n\times n}, M \in \mathbb{S}_+^{u\times u}$ and $N \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times u}$ are known.
Now, it seems to me that I have $n^2+nu$ free variables and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{u(u+1)}{2}+nu$ equations so when $n$ is sufficiently large, I should have possibly infinitely many solutions.
In such a case, is there a way to find these solutions?
My attempt so far was to solve the first equation for $A$ obtaining $A=(U_k\Lambda_K^{\frac 12} Q \Lambda_P^{-\frac 12} U_P^{\top})^{\top}$ where $U$ are the eigenvector matrices, $\Lambda$ the eigenvalue matrices and $Q$ is any $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix (notice that solutions exist because $P$ and $K$ are both positive-definite matrices, hence they have the same inertia).
By using the third equation we easily get $B = (A^{\top}P)^{-1}N$, I can substitute this into the second one, and using the expression that I found for $A$, we get an equation in the orthogonal matrix $Q$ that I don't even know if it can always be satisfied (because of the orthogonality constraint on $Q$).
Does anyone have thoughts on how to proceed?

Does $\mathbb S_+^{n\times n}$ denote positive-definite $n \times n$ matrices?

@RobertIsrael Yes.

A potentially interesting observation: this system can be written as the single equation
$$
\pmatrix{A&0\0 & B}^T
\pmatrix{P & P\P&P}
\pmatrix{A & 0\0 & B} =
\pmatrix{K & N\N^T & M}
$$

I'm assuming $S_+^{n \times n}$ denotes (symmetric) positive-definite matrices over $\mathbb R$.
Let $X =  P^{1/2} A K^{-1/2}$ and $Y  = P^{1/2} B M^{-1/2}$.  Then your equations become
$$ \eqalign{X^\top X &= I\cr
            Y^\top Y &= I\cr
            X^\top Y &= K^{-1/2} N M^{-1/2}\cr} $$
where $X$
The first two say $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal matrices.  But then $X^\top Y$ is also orthogonal, so a necessary condition for a solution to exist is that $K^{-1/2} N M^{-1/2}$ must be orthogonal.  If it is, then $X$ can be any orthogonal matrix and $Y = X K^{-1/2} N M^{-1/2}$.
[ EDIT ] That would be if $n = u$.  $X$, like $A$, is $n \times n$, while $Y$ is $n \times u$.  If $n < u$, it is impossible to have $Y^\top Y = I$, because $Y$ has rank at most $n$.  If $n > u$, $X$ is still orthogonal, and $X^T Y$ still satisfies $$(X^\top Y)^\top X^\top Y = Y^\top X X^\top Y = Y^\top Y = I$$
so the necessary and sufficient condition for solutions to exist is that
$K^{-1/2} N M^{-1/2}$ is semi-orthogonal in the sense that $(K^{-1/2} N M^{-1/2})^\top (K^{-1/2} N M^{-1/2}) = I$, and if so then for any $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix $X$ you can take $Y = X K^{-1/2} N M^{-1/2}$.

$B$ is non-square so I assume $Y$ would be semi-orthogonal right?

Oops, sorry, I misread. Will edit.
